# Convert razor enumdropdownlistfor to bootstrap button group dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor

I have a razor syntax enumdropdownlist for displaying either active/inactive status.

```
@Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.Status, new { @class = "btn btn-default btn-lg dropdown-toggle" })
```

I want to use a button group drop down with glyphs like I have below but don't know how to get my model value 'model.Status' to set the value of the button group drop down.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#item1').on('click', function() {
    $('#item0').text('Active');
  });

  $('#item2').on('click', function() {
    $('#item0').text('Not Listed');
  });

});
```

```html
<div class="btn-group">
  <button id="item0" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Action</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="caret"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li id="item1">
      <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></span>Active</a>
    </li>
    <li id="item2">
      <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>Not Listed</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I don't care if I use html or razor, I just want to use the boostrap button drop down with glyphs and I want to be able to set the enumerated view model value active/inactive (Status) when the page loads.

Answer (score 1):

Although the Bootstrap dropdown buttons look similar to a select list, their functionality is vastly different. I wouldn't recommend trying to use a Bootstrap dropdown button as a replacement for a select list if you need to actually post the "selected" item.

If you're just looking for a more stylistic and visually appealing alternative to a traditional select control, take a look at something like [Select2](https://select2.github.io/), and while the look is pleasant enough out of the box, there's also a [project](https://fk.github.io/select2-bootstrap-css/) that styles it to fit even better with the rest of Bootstrap.

If you're dead set on using Bootstrap dropdown buttons, you've got a lot of work ahead of you. You'll need to set up some JavaScript that will read the information from the select element and dynamically create the Boostrap dropdown button based on that, while hiding the original select. Then, you'll need to map over all the events such as a click on one of the items in the dropdown so that it selects the same item in the actual select element. You'll also have to account for highlighting the item in the dropdown that corresponds with the selected option in the select list, etc. If you run into specific problems while writing all that code, you can ask additional questions here as necessary, but providing you with all the code you'll need here is far beyond the scope of StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

In .cshtml file

```
<script>
     myModelStatus = '@Model.Status';
</script>

@Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.Status, new { @class = "btn btn-default btn-lg dropdown-toggle" })
more html here...
```

In your js file

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var status = myModelStatus;

  $('#item1').on('click', function() {
    $('#item0').text('Active');
  });

  $('#item2').on('click', function() {
    $('#item0').text('Not Listed');
  });

});
```

Comment: This line in my js file - var status = '@Model.Status'; just sets status = "@Model.Status" it doesn't fetch the actual value.

Comment: You have to put in the the .cshtml file to use the razor syntax. You can't use @Model.Status in a js file it has to be in the .cshtml

Answer (score 0):

You can try to enumerate through enum values and put them in page, please notice the `Html.HiddenFor` from the end, we will use it to store the **selected `Status`**.

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <button id="item0" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Action</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="caret"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    @{
        var values = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Status));
        for(int i=0; i < values.Count; i++)
        {
            var status = (Status)values[i];

            <li id="item@(i+1)" class="select-status" data-status="@values[i]">
              <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></span>@status.ToString()</a>
            </li>
        }
    }
  </ul>
</div>

@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Status)
```

After we create the html we have to update the selected `Status` in `Html.HiddenFor` to persist when a `POST` is performed.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.select-status').click(function(){
        $('#Status').val($(this).data('status')); // update the status in hidden input
    });

    @for(int i=0; i < values.Count; i++)
    {
        <text>
        $('#item@(i+1)').on('click', function() {
            $('#item0').text('@status.ToString()');
        });
        </text>
    }
});
```

HTML snippet example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.select-status').click(function(){
    $('#Status').val($(this).data('status')); // update the status in hidden input
  });
 
  
  $('#item1').on('click', function() {
    $('#item0').text('Active');
  });

  $('#item2').on('click', function() {
    $('#item0').text('Not Listed');
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn-group">
  <button id="item0" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Action</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="caret"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li id="item1" class="select-status" data-status="1">
      <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></span>Active</a>
    </li>
    <li id="item2" class="select-status" data-status="2">
      <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>Not Listed</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<br />
Visible Status just for test
<input type="text" id="Status" value="1" />
```

**Note:** The code may have some errors but the **logic/flow is the same**.

Answer (score -1):

- You are listening for click events on the li element rather than on the anchor tag
- You should stop event propagation by using event.preventDefault() method.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Yeah the site didnt allow me to comment when I wanted to. So I put it up as an answer. Sorry about that!